# How to get files stored in Elastic Beanstalk instance?

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django (1.10) app running in Elastic Beanstalk.
I want to dump some apps data to fixtures and download these fixtures to my local machine (to replicate in my local database).

So far, I've eb ssh'ed into my instance and dumped the data to ~/myapp_current.json.

But I can not find a way to copy the file to my local machine. There is no eb scp command.

Comment: Upload the file to an S3 bucket, and then download from there into your machine.

Comment: Thank you... so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `eb ssh` locally, `eb` will print out the actual SSH command it's running. For instance:

```
INFO: Running ssh -i /Users/me/.ssh/aws.pem ec2-user@3.4.5.6
```

Just copy that `ssh` command, change `ssh` to `scp`, and then add the rest, and run it locally:

```
scp -i /Users/me/.ssh/aws.pem ec2-user@3.4.5.6:myapp_current.json ./
```

Comment: Of all the questions and answers on SO about this, this is the only one that has come in handy. Tx Nick

Answer (score 0):

At your Environment there is the option "Application versions", in there you obtain a list of all the versions of your application that you had been upload. You can select the desired version and download it